Old Sci-Fi movie about a sister searching for her astronaut brother, lost in space
I'm searching for an old movie that has been a milestone in the lore of our family. My dad keeps retelling how my sister watched an old Sci-Fi b-movie about a brother and sister.
The brother (named "Wally"!) becomes an astronaut and goes off to space and is lost. The sister searches for him desperately.
The movie ends with a shot revealing that he is long dead, a skeleton floating in a space suit.
According to my dad, my sister had nightmares about this for weeks and my dad found it hilarious.

Could this be Moon Zero Two (1969)?

Also passing through the space port are Hubbard [Warren Mitchell], a wealthy businessman, and Clem Taplin [Catherine Schell]. Clem comes looking for Kemp because she knows he is a space pilot who has been to the far side of the moon. She is looking for her brother Wally, who had been mining a claim on the far side of the moon, but has disappeared. Kemp does not know him but shows her around the facilities that have been built to make the moon habitable.

They discover his body.

When they arrive there is no sign of life so they don space suits to go and investigate. They find Wally's body and discover he died because he had run out of oxygen while out looking for nickel.




